# QML property hint by dot notaton

Tags: properties, qml, qlist

```
class A{
    QList<B *>child;
    Q_INVOKABLE B * getChild(int idx) {return child.at(idx);}
}

class B{
    int age;
}

in QML:
Item{
  A{
    id: a;
  }
  Componet.onCompleted:{
    console.log: a.getChild(0).age;
  }
}
```

I have two classes  A and B.
I have register class A and B int main.cpp.
I can get the correct value, but I wish after a.getChild(0), to be able to get the reminder by dot notation if I do not know what property the class B have.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can iterate over all properties of object B in Qml. But you will get all the properties including signals and slots.

in QML:

```
Item{
  A {
    id: a;
  }
  Componet.onCompleted: {
    var bItem = a.getChild(0)
    for (var p in bItem )
       console.log(p + ": " + item[p]);
  }
}
```

This should return a list of properties and values, including age.

Comment: aah ok, he should have used the tag qtcreator then! I will leave the answer anyway, maybe it helps somebody else.

Comment: You could also mention `JSON.stringify(object)`, though for some reasons this does not seem to work at all times.